# Determining particle position in a magnetic field given initial conditions

Tags: electromagnetism, simulations

I am trying to create MATLAB code that will simulate a charged particle's path in a magnetic field. I have the user enter vectors for velocity and magnetic field, and then calculate the force vector.

Given these initial conditions, how can I calculate the position vector $[x,y,z]$ of the particle after time *t*? I'm aware of $\vec{F}=q\vec{V}×\vec{B}$, but am not sure how to determine position once force is found.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered maybe using [Newton's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_laws_of_motion)?

Comment: Just a note: the vector product symbol can be written: \times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newton's second law of motion is one way to derive a set of second order differential equations known as the equations of motion. We can write Newton's second law as:
$$\vec F=m\vec a(t)=m{d^2\vec r(t)\over dt^2},$$
where, $\vec a(t)$ and $\vec r(t)=x(t)\mathbf{\hat i}+y(t)\mathbf{\hat j}+z(t)\mathbf{\hat k},$ are the acceleration and position respectively. The velocity is given by:
$$\vec v(t)=x'(t)\mathbf{\hat i}+y'(t)\mathbf{\hat j}+z'(t)\mathbf{\hat k}.$$
In the case of a charged particle in a magnetic field:
$$\vec F=q\vec v\times\vec B\implies m{d^2\vec r(t)\over dt^2}=q\vec v\times\vec B.$$
So the vector product of $\vec v$ and $\vec B$ is given by:
$$\vec v\times \vec B=(y'(t)B_z-z'(t)B_y)\mathbf{\hat i}-(x'(t)B_z-z'(t)B_x)\mathbf{\hat j}+(x'(t)B_y-y'(t)B_x)\mathbf{\hat k}.$$
And the second derivative of the position $\vec r(t)$ as:
$${d^2\vec r(t)\over dt^2}=x''(t)\mathbf{\hat i}+y''(t)\mathbf{\hat j}+z''(t)\mathbf{\hat k}.$$ Putting this all together gives a set of *coupled* differential equations for the respective vector components:
$$\begin{align}
x''(t)&={q\over m}(y'(t)B_z-z'(t)B_y)\\
y''(t)&={q\over m}(x'(t)B_z-z'(t)B_x)\\
z''(t)&={q\over m}(x'(t)B_y-y'(t)B_x)
\end{align}$$
Now armed with the initial conditions for the problem, viz. the initial positions $x(0)=x_0$, $y(0)=y_0$, $z(0)=z_0$, and velocities $x'(0)=v_{x0}$, $y'(0)=v_{y0}$, $z'(0)=v_{z0}$, of the charged particle you can solve for the position as a function of time.

Comment: The last piece of this is [numeric integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration).  [RK4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) in particular is a popular choice.

Comment: @CortAmmon There is also an analytic solution.